# View table/collections inside container view not visible under translucent tab bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a container view on my root view controller with autolayout constraints of

[image]
[image: Root View Controller]

And I added a view controller inside the container view with

```
AddChildViewController(toViewController);
ContainerView.AddSubview(toViewController.View);
toViewController.View.LayoutIfNeeded();

UIView.Animate(0.5, () =>
{
   toViewController.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, ContainerView.Frame.Width, ContainerView.Frame.Height);
   toViewController.View.LayoutIfNeeded();

}, () =>
{
   toViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);
});
```

[image: Child View Controller]

Btw, below the "Label" is a CollectionView.
What I want to happen is like this.

[image]

The root view controller of the above image is UITableViewController and perfectly shows that there is a content behind it. But in the case for the UICollection view added on the container view. It just shows like this.

[image]

Any info would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint `Bottom Layout Guide.top = Container View.bottom` is the one causing this issue.

On your CardCollection view xib file make your you have these settings on the parent View:

[image]

Set the bottom constraint by ctrl-click-drag up to the parent View to see this:

[image]

if your hold alt you will get these options:

[image]

then just make sure that your container view goes past the tabbar like so:

[image]

Comment: Great. I didn't know the `Alt` option part.

Comment: Yeah its hidden well, found it one day when I was getting annoyed with autolayout.